# Why can I write an expression in an array declaration of a function argument in C?

Tags: c, gcc, syntax

Why does the following code compile without warnings or errors?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#ifdef __GNUC__
__attribute__((__const__))
#endif
int len(char** array) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; array[i]; i++);
    return i;
}
void inner_len(char** array, int out[len(array)]) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len(array); i++) {
        out[i] = strlen(array[i]);
    }
}
int main() {
    char* array[] = {
        "hello",
        "world",
        NULL
    };
    int ilen[1];
    inner_len(array, ilen);
}
```

Especially the function declaration of `inner_len` is what confuses me the most about this. I have seen gcc provide warnings for wrong array lengths. Is the expression in the function declaration ignored?

Comment: When declared as an argument, something like `int out[anything]` is  actually parsed as `int *out`. It's not possible to pass arrays as arguments, only pointers to their first element.

Comment: And note that you will go out of bounds of the `out` (i.e. the `ilen`) array. C have no bounds-checking either, it's up to you to make sure that your program doesn't go out of bounds.

Comment: What warnings are you expecting? If you add `-Wvla -Wmissing-prototypes` you will get some warnings.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I know this, but I was wondering, why I didn't get a size warning, like I would get when I would write `int out[2]` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did here is to declare a variable length array. If you compile it as ISO C89, you get:

```
$ gcc --std c89 -pedantic -Wall bla.c
bla.c:9:1: warning: ISO C90 forbids variable length array ‘out’ [-Wvla]
    9 | void inner_len(char** array, int out[len(array)]) {
      | ^~~~
```

But as C99 there is no warning, since ISO C99 added variable length arrays, refer to, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array#C99.

Note that `out` is still an ordinary pointer, as usually in C when you pass an array as argument to a function. And there is also no compile time length check here, since the compiler does run/evaluate the code in the function `len()`, other than when you'd used a literal like `int out[2]`.

Comment: Re “the compiler does run/evaluate the code in the function len()”: This is not specified by the C standard and different compilers implement it differently. The C standard says that a parameter declared to be an array is “adjusted” to be a pointer, but it does not says whether this is done notionally before or after the expression inside the `[ … ]` is evaluated. Clang 14.0.0 evaluates the expression. GCC 11.2 does not.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, the standard writes that the "declarations" are adjusted. The term "declaration" exists only during parsing thus it suggests there is no VLA type there. So the standard seems to say that the declaration is literally the same as `void inner_len(char** array, int* out)`. Thus no size expressions is evaluated because there is actually no size expression there.

Comment: @tstanisl: I am not aware of anything in the C standard that states or implies “The term "declaration" exists only during parsing.” Cite the specific clause and paragraph for that. C 2018 6.2.4 6 implies otherwise; it says initialization is performed “each time the declaration… is reached in the execution of the block,” so the declaration must exist, notionally, during execution. C 2018 6.8 3 says “… the variable length array declarators of ordinary identifiers with block scope, are evaluated… each time the declaration is reached in the order of execution, as if it were a statement…”

Comment: @tstanisl: If a declaration existed only during parsing, then `int x[printf("Hello, world.\n")];` would not print anything even when this declaration appears inside a function body, not in the list of parameters. But it is printed. Variable length array declarators must be evaluated for declarations of arrays that are not function parameters (including arrays that are inside function parameters, such as a pointer to a variable length array type) in order for the array to be implemented, so it cannot be that this aspect of the declaration “does not exist” during execution.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, Firstly, the 6.2.4p6 not  referring to VLA. There is a similar wording in 6.7.8p3 but it refers to `typedef` which is forbidden in the parameter lists. So this rule does not apply here. The real problem whether it is actually a VLA declarator. The standard says `A declaration of a parameter as ''array of type'' shall be adjusted to ''qualified pointer to type`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, I don't think that the declaration can change its type type in during execution, so `out` must be a `int*` from the very beginning. Especially when the value passed fro the caller was already transformed from an array to a pointer. Thus there is no VLA type declared here and "size expressions" must be ignored.

Comment: @tstanisl: I did not say 6.2.4 6 says anything about variable length arrays. As I indicated, it shows the standard speaking of declarations as if they exist during execution time, thus contradicting your assertion that the term “declaration” exists only during parsing. Cite the specific clause and paragraph of the C standard for your assertion that “The term "declaration" exists only during parsing.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil, there is no such clause. The issue is that the declaration is a part of AST and 6.7.6.3p7 tells that the type of declaration shall be adjusted to a pointer. Note that this point refers both to a function's definition and to the prototype where no execution can take place. This issue is unrelated to the execution. To my understanding it means that `void foo(int a[f()]) { ... }` it literally equivalent to  `void foo(int *a) { ... }` and effectively there is no "size expression" and no definition of any VLA type in the former definition. So no `f()` shall be called.

Comment: @tstanisl: Re “there is no such clause.” So, the standard does not say what you asserted, that “The term "declaration" exists only during parsing.” As I wrote, the behavior regarding evaluation of a size expression in a parameter declared as an array is not specified by the C standard. The C standard does not say when the adjustment conceptually occurs. You can interpret it as you please, but, as a matter of fact, **the C standard does not say this**.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, I am not sure if "when" matters. The type is either `int*` or `int[f()]`. One requires evaluation of `f()`, while the other does not. To my understanding 6.7.6.3p7 requires the type of parameter to **be** `int*`. This adjustment does not happen on every invocation. It happens only **once** when the function is defined. The declaration is adjusted, not the value of parameter. If it happened on every invocation then I could agree with you. The type must be `int*`, not VLA type and the size expression must be ignored. I must admit that I am myself surprised with this conclusion.

Comment: @tstanisl: Re “This adjustment does not happen on every invocation”: The C standard does not say that. Clang authors have decided differently than you.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, functions are defined once, not on every invocation. Maybe CLANG's autors choose wrong.. it happens from time to time.

Comment: @tstanisl: You have whatever mental model you have of C. But, as I wrote, the C standard does not say this. Reading its conceptual model, it does say that preprocessing directives are deleted during translation, in phase 4. It says no such thing for declarations. There is nothing in the standard that says declarations, or information and behavior derived from them, cannot be conceptually held all throughout program execution, in whatever translated form they have, just as statements, or information and behavior derived from them (e.g., instructions), can be held throughout execution.

Comment: @tstanisl: Insisting on whatever you think is the case for when declarations are handled in whichever way is useless. It just tells us what you think. And that is not in dispute. The issue is that the C standard does not specify this. There are not words in it that say these things. When you assert these things, it does not advance any argument that they are specified by the C standard. To advance such an argument, you must demonstrate words in the C standard that support it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, Unfortunately, the C standard is not written as a formal specification. There is a great space for interpretation. I perceive a declaration as part of AST of the program. It is supposed to be defined and adjusted only once even if C were an interpreted language. VMT requires some evaluation to complete their types, but declaration must be VMT in the first place. Frankly, I've always thought that those size expressions must be always executed until your comment that it is not specified. After deeper reading I tend to think that it should never be executed.

Comment: @tstanisl: Re “VMT requires some evaluation to complete their types, but declaration must be VMT in the first place”: A parameter declared as a variable-length array is a variably modified type in the first place. It is only not a variably modified type after adjustment. The C standard does not say when that adjustment occurs. Re “I perceive…”: See above regarding the relevance of your thoughts. Words in the C standard are applicable to the argument about whether the C standard specifies this. Your thoughts are not applicable.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, I don't agree. The parameter can have only one type. Either VLA or a pointer. And C standard says it is a pointer, not VLA. The problem is if this dummy VLA type actually needs to be completed by evaluation the "size expression" even though this type is never going to be used. To my understanding the declaration is a part of definition so the adjustment should happen only once. It is not the same as array decay where the runtime-defined value of array  is converted to a pointer.

Comment: @tstanisl: Re “I don't agree”: Your agreement is not relevant. Cite words in the standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, can you tell that does `Array expressions and function designators as arguments were converted to
pointers before the call` from 6.9.1p10 mean?

Comment: @tstanisl: Make your case. I am not interested in some challenge-and-response contest.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, that 6.9.1p10 starts with `On entry to the function,` while 6.7.6.3p7 does not use the same wording except the case of `static` keyword. The similar wording is in 6.7.8p3 for `typedef`. By "Exception that proves the rule", it suggests that the adjustment is not done at each invocation (implicit rule) if not stated otherwise (exception). So the adjustment must be only done once during the definition of the function. There is no argument to think otherwise. There is no VMT in `void foo(int a[f()])` and `f()` should never be called. That is my case.

Comment: What happened here?

Comment: @tstanisl: Okay, the contrast between paragraphs 7 and 10 there may shift the balance to doing the adjustment early.

Comment: @Tenobaal: A language-lawyer discussion about esoteric aspects of the C standard.